# Test for existence of a linear trend in a time series

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, trend

I want to know whether there is a time linear trend in a time series. What are some good approaches? One approach seems to test that the model belongs to ARMA(p,q) family however I am not sure if a test exists for this purpose. If necessary I am willing to specify p and q and I am open to other approaches.

Comment: Do you know the distinction between a model being a linear model and a model being a line?

Comment: I am asking for existence of a term proportional to time.

Comment: The correlation between time as a degenerate stochastic process and some stochastic process that is indexed by time will itself be a random variable. If you want to perform a null hypothesis test you will need some distributional assumptions for this random correlation $R$.

Comment: @Galen I can assume $y_{t+1} = \beta y_t + \sigma \epsilon_t + a + b t$. I want to test that $b=0$ and $a=0$.

Comment: Okay, assuming that recurrence relation is a good step. What can we assume about the distributions of $Y_t$ and $\epsilon_t$?

Comment: @Galen Noise can be standard normal. I want to basically describe an ARMA(1) process with the difference that mean is increasing with time.

Comment: What software do you use - R?

Comment: @Ute, I use python at the moment. But it is more important that I understand how the test works.

Comment: Several approaches are discussed in [this thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/5149/237561) - have you seen this before?